# rotate a string and print out the lexicographically largest rotation

Tags: python, string, algorithm, rotation, lexicographic

```py
s = raw_input()
n = len(s)
el = []
z = n - 1
while z >= 0:
    x = s[z:] + s[:z]
    z = z - 1
    el.append(x)
print max(el)
```

The code is working fine but it is very inefficient.
Is there a more time efficient method to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

You can solve this in linear time using [suffix arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). Given the input string `s`, construct the doubled string `ss`. Use a linear-time algorithm to construct the suffix array of `ss`. The suffix array holds the indices of the suffices of `ss` in lexicographic order. Finally, scan backwards through the suffix array, skipping over the indices that are in the second half of `ss`. The lexicographically largest suffix starting in the first half of `ss` can then be trimmed to a rotation of `s`.

The problem is similar to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61848794/glass-beads-how-does-suffix-array-applied-here/63079071#63079071), except that problem is about the lexicographically smallest rotation, and you want the lexicographically largest rotation.

### Implementation

The article linked above mentions some of the algorithms you could use for the suffix array construction. I will not give an explicit construction for this part here, but for a Python implementation, see for example this [article](https://zork.net/%7Est/jottings/sais.html).

So assuming you have some implementation of a suffix array algorithm `create_suffix_array(s: str) -> [int]`, such that `create_suffix_array(s)` returns the index sequence of the suffices in lexicographic order, you can then apply the algorithm to your problem like this:

```
def rotate(s: str, n: int) -> str:
  return s[n:] + s[:n]

def solve(s: str) -> str:
  indices: [int] = create_suffix_array(s + s)

  is_first_half = lambda i: i < len(s)

  best_index = next(filter(is_first_half, reversed(indices)))

  return rotate(s, best_index)
```

### Correctness of the algorithm

Let `s` be a string of length `n`. Let `i` be the index of the lexicographically largest suffix of `ss` that is starting in the first half of `ss`. The suffix of `ss` that is defined by `i` is `s[i,n-1]s`.

Consider any `j` in `[0,n-1]`. Then the suffix of `ss` that is defined by `j` cannot be larger than `s[i,n-1]s`. So `s[j,n-1]s <= s[i,n-1]s`. Then it follows that any two equal-sized prefixes of these suffices have the same ordering. In particular, `s[j,n-1]s[0,j-1] <= s[i,n-1]s[0,i-1]`, since both are `n`-sized prefixes of the two suffices.

Therefore, `s[i,n-1]s[0,i-1]` is the lexicographically largest rotation of `s`.